# Highcharts: possible to force datalabel to overlap y-axis?

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to force the "PB" data label to sit centrally in the ellipse so that it overlaps the y-axis?

http://jsfiddle.net/w4ez0L4n/

I've set `allowOverlap` to `true` but that only appears to refer to other data labels, not other chart elements.

Thanks

Code from JSfiddle:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'scatter',
    marginRight: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    style: {
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
    },
    zoomType: 'xy'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Finish line plot'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    opposite: true,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    reversed: true,
    title: {
      text: 'seconds back'
    },
    min: 0
  },
  yAxis: {
    opposite: true,
    gridLineWidth: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    },
    lineWidth: 2,
    title: {
      text: 'Finish line'
    },
    lineColor: '#000'
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        align: 'center',
        allowOverlap: true,
        formatter: function() {
          return this.point.name;
        },
        x: 0,
        y: 10,
        style: {
          textOutline: 'none'
        },
        enabled: true
      }
    },
    scatter: {
      marker: {
        fillColor: '#686',
        symbol: 'url(https://www.iconshock.com/image/Golden/Graphics/ellipse/)',
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        states: {
          hover: {
            enabled: true,
            lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
          }
        }
      },
      states: {
        hover: {
          marker: {
            enabled: false
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<b>Competitor info:</b><br>',
        pointFormat: '{point.x} seconds back'
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Male',
    color: 'rgba(119, 152, 191, .5)',
    data: [{
        x: 0,
        y: 85,
        name: 'PB'
      },
      {
        x: 5.3,
        y: 71.8,
        name: 'VB'
      },
      {
        x: 3.5,
        y: 80.7,
        name: 'SF'
      },
      {
        x: 6.5,
        y: 72.6,
        name: 'RW'
      },
      {
        x: 7.2,
        y: 78.8,
        name: 'LH'
      },
      {
        x: 1.5,
        y: 74.8,
        name: 'CM'
      },
      {
        x: 1.7,
        y: 93.8,
        name: 'SH'
      },
      {
        x: 1.5,
        y: 70.0,
        name: 'TM'
      },
      {
        x: 3.0,
        y: 72.4,
        name: 'WP'
      },
      {
        x: 6.0,
        y: 85.9,
        name: 'DH'
      }
    ]
  }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see [Highcharts documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.overflow)

Setting properties `crop` and `overflow` for the `dataLabels` should do the trick:

```
...
series: [{
    dataLabels:{
      crop: false,
      overflow: 'none'
    },
    name: 'Male',
...
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w4ez0L4n/7/)

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't realised it being outside of the bounds of the chat was the issue and had searched extensively for overlap-related terms!

Comment: Yes, it can be a bit of a hassle to find the correct place where a change is actually doing what you are expecting :)

Comment: I couldn't agree more, and it only gets more complicated as time goes on. It really puts me off doing things in HC to be honest, if you don't work on them all the time so the ins and outs are fresh in your mind they're very time consuming, unless you're happy with a very basic chart. Impressively powerful tool though, not much that it can't do!